# lag of app_remove giving null result set

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out the last 3 events before app removal for each user.
Here is my code so far:

```
   select
    lag(event_name,3) over(partition by user_pseudo_id order by event_timestamp) as lag_event_name_3,
    lag(event_name,2) over(partition by user_pseudo_id order by event_timestamp) as lag_event_name_2,
    lag(event_name) over(partition by user_pseudo_id order by event_timestamp) as lag_event_name
    from table_name
    where event_name = 'app_remove'
    and user_pseudo_id in (select * from dataset)
```

The problem is that I am getting a null result set. Am I missing something here? Thanks

Comment: maybe you have only one row, add a second or add event_name to the query

Comment: "select count(*) from dataset" results in 144259 rows

Comment: but you partition by user_pseudo_id  so if every user_pseudo_id has one row the lags are all NULL, hat why i said add event_name

Comment: can you please tell where to add event_name

Comment: `SELECT event_name, lag(event_name,3)....`  and you see there is only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this suggestion as answer by @nbk for the visibility of the community.

Adding another field in the select clause to fill the null values due to partitioned records.

> SELECT event_name, lag(event_name,3)...

A good reference for window functions here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_spec